# How to resolve this problem ? it s with webpack or not?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/CradleLoader.css 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   .swing div {

In webpack.config.js:

```
{
            test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'react'),
            ],
            use: [

                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,

                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 2,
                        minimize: !devMode
                    }
                },

                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: [

                            autoprefixer({
                                browsers: [
                                    '>5%',
                                    'last 2 versions',
                                    'not ie < 9',
                                ],


                            }),


                        ]
                    }

                },

                'sass-loader'
            ]
        },
```

Comment: You are sure, this package are installed in your project ? Otherwise, try to `yarn remove nameofyourpackage` or if you use `npm` search for removing a package. 
And I try to re-install this package :)

Comment: don't apply sass-loader and post-css loader to css, split that rule into scss and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are sying webpack to use your rule only for files inside 
`path.resolve(__dirname, 'react')`

```
{
   test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
   include: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, 'react'),
   ]
```

but somwhere in your code you import that file `./node_modules/react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/CradleLoader.css` and it is not inside `path.resolve(__dirname, 'react')` so webpack don't transpile it.

**Simpliest solution is to remove that from your config.**

```
   include: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, 'react'),
   ]
```

**or add that module to your `include` array:**

```
   include: [
       path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
       path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/CradleLoader.css'),
   ],
```